# Tesseract(OCR) throwing exception "System.AccessViolationException" while using the trained Tessedata

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to implement the OCR(Optical character recognition) in my project using the TESSERACT 3.20 (open source) component.
As per the Tesseract instruction I have trained the tessedata files for new language.Then I have done coding(C#) in my page for convert image to text(OCR) conversion with new tessedata folder which is created by me .Finally I am running my project,the code is throwing the exception like:"System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory" but when I'm using the default(English) tessedata files that same code is returning the corresponding output.How to fix this issue?

Comment: Perhaps, your `traineddata` file was not properly created.

Comment: problem is version mismatch with version3.02(trained tessedata) and version2.0(tessnet2_32.dll).So how develop the OCR concept using 3.02 version trained data in C#.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26602383/how-to-use-tesseract-3-02-trained-data-in-c